# jquery handle asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using query callback function call like below.

```
function load()
 $.each(modules, function(index, module) {
 // do something here
 feed.load(callback);
 }
}

function callback (result) {
  var my_dynamic_div = something random div id; // this is present in dom
  $(my_dynamic_div).append(result);
}
```

what is happening here is when i have single item in each it loads correctly.
but if there are multiple items in modules array it is only loading last one.

Any one have any idea how i should handle it.

Basically i want to load each call to callback to respective div.

Thank you.

Comment: Notice: you call `feed.load(callback)` `modules.length`-times. There is no difference between calling it one time or n-times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encapsulate it in an anonymous function like this

```
function load()
 $.each(modules, function(index, module) {
 // do something here
 feed.load(function(result){callback(result);});
 }
}

function callback (result) {
  var my_dynamic_div = something random div id; // this is present in dom
  $(my_dynamic_div).append(result);
}
```